# How to encodeURIComponent in each object iteration using MustacheJS

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I want to store each object in a `data` attribute in HTML with Mustache.
Here is my sample `object`

```
{
 people: [
         {
          "name": "Person1",
          "age": 21

         },
         {
          "name": "Person2",
          "age": 23

         },             
         {
          "name": "Person3",
          "age": 25

         }
         ]
}
```

I rendered it in HTML .

```
 {{#people}}
    <div id="person" data-person-object={{.}}>
      {{name}}
      {{age}}
    </div>
 {{/people}}
```

I want to store each iteration of object in `data-person-object` and I want to use `encodeURIComponent` and it seems that the markdown renders `data-person-obj="[object" object]`

Any suggestions pls.

Comment: I suppose you want something like: display person object as JSON string, and then to apply encodeURIComponent on the resulting string. But I don't think that (or I'm not sure if) mustache supports outputting objects as JSON string. You will probably need to do a manual for-loop and for each iteration to call the function JSON.stringify()